# Why is Steiner's proof of isoperimetric inquality incorrect?

Tags: geometry

I've just read an exposition of an [attempted proof](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/ab/GeometrieWerkstatt/IsoperimetricInequality.pdf) of Isoperimetric Inequality, by Andreas Hehl, with the argument attributed to Steiner.

The statement of the theorem is as follows:

Let $c(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ be a simple, closed, positively oriented and regular parametrised
$C^1$ curve with $t \in [a, b]$. Denote the area enclosed in the above defined curve $c(t)$ with A. For a given length $l$ of $c(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, we have

$$A \leq \frac{l^2}{4\pi}$$

with equality iff $c(t)$ is a circle.

The proof proceeds by a clever symmetrisation argument & is perhaps too long and (presumably) well known to give here.

The author of the document doesn't find the proof convincing:

> While this construction is intuitively accessible, it cannot be seen
>   as a complete proof of the Isoperimetric Inequality. It merely gives
>   one way to construct the biggest area enclosed in a curve with fixed
>   length $l$, namely the circle. Yet, we have not shown the existence of a
>   (unique) solution, so we have to see this ’proof’ as incomplete.

Contrary to the author of the document, I find the proof entirely convincing:

1. If $c(t)$ is concave, it will enclose area smaller than a corresponding convex curve (see the pdf for exact meaning behind "corresponding convex curve").
2. If $c(t)$ is convex, but is not a circle with perimeter $l$, it will have area smaller than the circle.
3. Circle of perimeter $l$ has an area of $l^2/(r\pi)$, which can be easily shown using limits and the inscribed/outscribed polygons trick going back to Archimedes'.

We have then that if c(t) is not a circle, it has area less than the area of a circle with perimeter $l$, which is $l^2/(r\pi)$ so we get a strict inequality. If $c(t)$ is a circle we get equality. What is the catch?

Comment: I can't find the proof of 1 in the pdf. All I found was a proof that, if $c(t)$ is not convex, it will enclose a smaller area than another curve with the same perimeter; but **that other curve is not necessarily convex**. What am I missing?

Comment: Good point. I've jumped a few steps here (perhaps unsoundly). The way I imagined the "convexisation" of the curve happening was by repeatedly applying the trick of making a non-convex part of the curve convex until the curve is entirely convex. The intuition is then that this eventually gives us a convex curve. But I wouldn't be surprised if this is untrue/ hard to prove.

At the very least, following Steiner's argument, have we proven that if another solution to the isoperimetric inequality exist it must be non-convex?

Comment: A rectifiable curve can have infinitely many "saw teeth". Then no finite iteration of Steiner's construction will transform it into a convex curve.

Comment: I don't think the "saw teeth" we'd get would be very sharp, at least after finitely many applications of Steiner's construction, since the curve is smooth to start with But I see the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Steiner's argument establishes the following new claims:

1. If $c(t)$ encloses a concave area, then there is **some other curve** of the same length but enclosing a larger area.
2. If $c(t)$ encloses a convex area but is not a circle, then there is **some other curve** of the same length but enclosing a larger area.

The third claim you list is correctly stated, but it is not new. It is also irrelevant to the hole in the proof.

Whether the other curve in the above claims encloses a convex area or not is irrelevant. The important point is that the other curves Steiner constructs are **not** circles. So, Steiner's argument proves just the following implication: **IF** $c$ is a closed curve such that for every closed curve $c'$ of the same length, it holds that the area enclosed by $c$ is larger than or equal to the area enclosed by $c'$, **THEN** $c$ is a circle. A separate argument is needed to show that such an extremal curve exists.

The hole in Steiner's attempted proof is perhaps easier to see by considering the following analogous argument, which obviously does **not** show that 1 is the smallest positive real number.

Let $x$ be a positive real number such that $x\neq 1$. Then $x^2-x=x(x-1)\neq 0$. If $x^2<x$, then $x^2$ is a positive real number less than $x$. On the other hand, if $x^2>x$, then $x(x-1)>0$, so $x-1>0$, and consequently 1 is a positive real number less than $x$. Hence, for every positive real number $x$ such that $x\neq 1$, there is another positive real number $y$ such that $y<x$.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Another way to see it would be: Let $c_0$ be a closed, smooth, etc. curve, which is not a circle. Applying Steiner's construction inductively gives us an infinite sequence $c_0$, $c_1$, $\ldots$, which is monotone with respect to the areas enclosed by subsequent curves. If we can't prove that the sequence is bounded from above with respect to the curve area, we're cooked. If we can prove that the sequence is bounded from above we can apply monotone convergence theorem and get a supremum, but this isn't guaranteed to be smaller than the area of the circle.

Comment: Also a strictly increasing countably infinite sequence bounded (or not) from above doesn't have a maximum, which is another way to see that Steiner's proof shows that if an area-maximising curve exists, it must be a circle. But indeed a separate argument is needed to show existence.